# Angular 7: div innerHTML binding not working with or without html sanitization for location html data

Tags: angular

Source for my data comes from a REST endpoint which is an html content.
Once I got the data I tried to put in innerHTML like
`<div [innerHTML]="mydata"></div>` but it did not work. Just to be sure `mydata` has data, I tried to print the `mydata` using interpolation like `{{mydata}}` and it works fine. I then searched around and found that `mydata` needs to be sanitised as Angular doesn't allows it due to security concerns. So I created a pipe in which I sanitized it using
`this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(mydata)` but even after this it's not working.

Note: I did try the same code with a simple HTML content and it worked fine. `mydata` in problematic case has location data.

Code to Sanitize:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, 
SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
   name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | 
    SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
        case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);              
        case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
        case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
        case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
        case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
        default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
```

and then I call like:
`<div [innerHTML]="mydata | safe :'html'"></div>`

Based on the answers by @James Essex
I modified the code to:

location.service.ts:
     import { Observable } from "rxjs"

```
 getData(): Observable <any> {
    return this.http.get(sourceUrl, { responseType: 'text'}).pipe(
      tap(value =>  {
        console.log(value);
     })
    );  
  }
```

component.ts
    `responseDataFromObservable: any;
     ngOnInit(){
     this.callLocationData();

```
 callLocationData() {
this.locationService.getData().subscribe(response => {
  response = this.responseDataFromObservable;
     })
   }
 }
```

and html is: exactly what @ James Essex said.

But still no luck, and UI is showing blank screen without any errors.

Comment: This is intended behavior.  Please post the code that has the sanitization that isn't working.

Comment: @Phix: I modified the question with the code to Sanitize

Comment: What does `mydata` look like?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten: This is a Folium(python-visualization/folium: Python Data. Leaflet.js ... - GitHub) generated html file. It has multiple CDN, style, script sections. Unfortunately I can not share all those entries here. However  its generated using leaflet.js.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you should be trying to bypass security and or injecting raw HTML into a `<div [innerHTML]="myData">`.  This seems to be in direct violation of the [Angular security documents](https://angular.io/guide/security) for cross-sight scripting.

The template layer uses a shadow DOM to not directly touch the HTML directly and it can be accessed easily by `Renderer2`.

I would recommend developing a Directive instead which uses, `Renderer2` and `ElementRef`:

#### EXAMPLE:

Angular Directive:

```js
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSafeData]'
})
export class SafeDataDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input passedHtmlData;

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef,
) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, passedHtmlData);
  }
}
```

Corresponding Service:

```js
  getData(): Observable<any> {
    this.http.get('putUrlHere');
  }
```

Corresponding Component:

```js
  let responseDataFromObservable; // Put whatever type it is string, interfaced typings or any?

  ngOnInit() {
    callLocationData();
  }

  callLocationData() {
    this.locationService.getData().subscribe(response => {
      response = this.responseDataFromObservable;
    }
  }
```

Corresponding HTML:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="responseDataFromObservable">
  <div appSafeData [passedHtmlData]="responseDataFromObservable" id="my-data-wrapper">
    <!-- Your API data as HTML will be added here -->
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

NOTE: I am sure there might be a better of setting up the Template using `<ng-container>` but something like this is a much better way to injecting the data with out compromising security.

Additional Links that might help:

1. [Alligator.io - Using Renderer2](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/)
2. [Alligator.io - Using ng-container](https://alligator.io/angular/ng-container-element/)
3. [Angular.io - Renderer2 Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Comment: I agree completely. I tried the solution you gave: 
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSafeData]'
})
export class SafeDataDirective implements OnInit{
 constructor(private locationService: LocationService, private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.locationService.getData());
  }
}
html
<ng-container *ngIf="locationService.getData()"> <div appSafeData id="my-data-wrapper"></div></ng-container>
but getting: 
ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Comment: is locationService.getData() an Observable?

does your service method look like this?
getData(): Observable<any> {
  this.http.get('urlGoesHere');
}
From this call you can call on ngOnInit in the Component a locationService.getData().subscribe(response => this.setResponseDataToNewPropertyOnComponent)
Then add on the Directive an if you put an @Input() directiveData.
and pass in the Template <div appSaveData [directiveData]=''setResponseDataToNewPropertyOnComponent'>
Change the ngIf to only show if you have saved this response data to the component. Sorry if this is hard to understand.

Comment: @KanhaiyaChoudhary I updated my response above to reflect what i said in the last message.

Comment: @ James Essex: I modified the code according to your solution (same I modified in the question details here too) but still no luck. UI is showing blank page without any errors.

Comment: Another thing is that file itself(response size) is around 4MB, do you see any problem?

Comment: Just to rule out the case of 4MB, when I directly used in an html page w/o Angular from it works fine

Comment: Another thing I observed is that when I inspect I see html data however its not rendering on UI. UI is blank. Even view source shows different stuffs.

Comment: Hi @JamesEssex I'm not sure I see the difference between injecting the html as innerHTML or appending it via Renderer2  - if there's no sanitization being done, this amounts to the same thing right?