# Angular 9: [innerHTML] not working without sanitizing the value even for plain string

Tags: javascript, angular, innerhtml

I have 2 angular 9 apps in monospace.

The following code prints no text on the browser document in one of the app,

Component:

```
myText = "some text"
```

Template:

```
<p [innerHtml]="myText"><p>
```

If i write anything inside the paragraph even that is not getting printed:

```
<p [innerHtml]="myText">Test<p>         // Test is also not getting printed
```

However,If i **sanitize** the `myText` value it works fine.

Component:

```
// sanitizer is injected DomSanitizer service
myText  = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("some text");
```

Template:

```
<p [innerHtml]="myText"><p>
```

But in my other app it works fine.

Has anyone come across similar issue? Is there any app configuration or something which has made sanitization mandatory for innerHTML?

Comment: If you're just inserting text and not an HTML tags, why not just use `{{value}}` instead of setting `[innerHtml]`. I don't believe `innerHtml` can be set without sanitation.

Comment: Either way, this looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58290396), which explains the issue in exhaustive detail. It's an intended design of Angular due to potential security issues of setting `innerHtml` without sanitation.

Comment: As a test: what do you see if you put `{{ myText }}` in the view?

Answer (score 1):

`innterHTML` will clear out any HTML found within that element (quite literally, the *inner html*). If you want to add additional HTML to the template, you'll have to do it in a separate element:

```
<p [innerHtml]="myText"><p>
<p>some more text</p>
```

One another thing that you might explore doing is creating your appended value within your TypeScript and appending that to your variable that's getting referenced in the `[innerHTML]` binding. That would give you a way to stick with one element as opposed to having to append another.

Basically, this is a very similar issue with using something like `document.write`. `document.write` clears out the HTML and inserts whatever you passed in. Same thing happens with `innerHTML`

Basic example of what's happening. Note that "Place holder text" gets completely cleared when `innerHTML` is set.

```js
const exampleDiv = document.getElementById('example');
exampleDiv.innerHTML = 'This is some text';
```

```html
<div id="example">Place holder text</div>
```

So, here are your options:

```js
const exampleDiv = document.getElementById('example1');
const someTextIWantAppended = 'Some appended text';

exampleDiv.innerHTML = `Some Inner HTML I want. ${someTextIWantAppended}`;

// OR

const exampleDiv2 = document.getElementById('example2');

exampleDiv2.innerHTML = `Some Inner HTML I want.`;
```

```html
<strong>Example 1</strong>
<div id="example1"></div>

<hr />

<strong>Example 2</strong>
<div id="example2"></div>
<div>Some appended text</div>
```